# SQL Error: ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

Why do I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select name,major, lpad(to_char(date_birth,'dd'),10) "Date of birth",
to_char(next_day(date_birth,'sunday'),'dd') - to_char(date_birth,'dd') "Different in days"
from students
```

> SQL Error: ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week
>   01846. 00000 -  "not a valid day of the week"

when I run the following query?

```
select name,major, lpad(to_char(date_birth,'dd'),10) "date of birth",
to_char(next_day(date_birth,'sunday'),'dd') - to_char(date_birth,'dd') "Different in days" from students
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the error or just a typo in your question, but the error message has `date_bith` instead of `date_birth`.

Comment: @rojib: It looks like you have NOT accepted a single answer you have asked in SO so far. Accept the answers that solved your problem.

Comment: I have extrapolated your table and tested your query.  It runs without error.  [Check out this SQL Fiddle for proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beaf20/1) .  So your problem is either in your data or in some element of your data structure/query which you left out when editing it to post here.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing next_day(date_birth,'sunday') to next_day(date_birth,1) -- 1 stands for the first day of the week i.e. Sunday

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the name of the days in the language that you have set on sql developer, which is most likely not english.
But best practice is to set integers, like @user4507518 said.